# Alt key not working on Dell Inspiron 7437

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, keyboard-layout

I have just installed Ubuntu 23.10 in my Dell Inspiron 7437 old laptop. Also Im new to Linux as well, but experienced user for Windows. I have tried to change Keyboard layout from English(US, Intern, alt), English (US), English(US, intern, with dead keys), and `Alt` keys are not working (Left and Right). It was working properly on windows 10 btw.
The reason I need International is to use the special characters such as `Ç` for Brazillian Portuguese, which is working fine.

Ubuntu language is running in Brazillian Portuguese as well.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Tested with a external keyboard and `Alt` works fine.
2. I installed a VM for Zorin OS using Boxes, and the same scenario, only external keyboard works the key `alt`. The laptop keyboard remains the same.
3. There is no BIOS updates.
4. Tried to run Live Ubuntu from usb, the same.

[Keyboard reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPPSp.jpg)

Any ideas to try?

Comment: Do you see the keypresses in `sudo evtest` and `xev`?

Comment: Yes. But only the Alt right key. KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x243, subw 0x0, time 29164372, (165,-19), root:(215,68),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: 2 part
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x243, subw 0x0, time 29164514, (165,-19), root:(215,68),
    state 0x80, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: If the left alt key isn't showing in `evtest`, then the kernel isn't seeing it. Look in BIOS for settings related to the keyboard, or look for a function key that disables that key

Comment: Event: time 1709326873.069325, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b8
Event: time 1709326873.069325, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT), value 1
Event: time 1709326873.069325, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1709326873.193236, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b8
Event: time 1709326873.193236, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT), value 0
Event: time 1709326873.193236, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------